# unable to uninstall an android app

Tags: android, uninstallation

I Mistakenly installed an android application called [ereadz](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mvm) and now I noticed that it installed as a system app and there's no way to get rid of it. I don't want to root my phone, is there any way to get rid of it without rooting the phone?

Comment: Is the App listed in your application manager?

Comment: yes it's on all tab in application manager but doesn't have uninstall option and I can only disable it there.

Comment: may be this question should be asked on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: see  this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2521768?hl=en-CA)

Comment: uninstall using google play store app

Comment: it's not possible ,it seems there's no way to uninstall it

Comment: you will get answers to such questions on Android Enthusiasts which is one of the client of Stack Exchange community..... [here is the link to similar question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20903/can-i-convert-a-system-app-to-a-user-app-uninstall-it-or-move-it-to-my-sd-card)....hope this helps....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is now an system app, unless you root your phone you can't uninstall it. But, you can try to disable it in the ap